# Using javascript to derive height of image when only resized width is explicitly given in html

Tags: javascript

Forgive my ignorance of javascript, but I'm trying to create a simple image hover that enlarges the image when you hover your mouse over it. (And no, I don't want to use JQuery. I want to learn this directly in javascript!) My problem is that only the width is specified in the html. The height is omitted so that the image displays proportionally on the page. When I hover over the image with my mouse, the javascript works fine in IE, but in FF, Chrome, Safari, etc. img.offsetHeight gets assigned 0 rather than a proportion of img.offsetWidth.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var img=document.getElementById('imageid'); 
     var thiswidth=img.offsetWidth;
     var thisheight=img.offsetHeight;
     var ratio=thisheight/thiswidth;
     var bigwidth=600;
     var bigheight=bigwidth*ratio;
      function bigImg(x) {
        x.style.width=bigwidth;
        x.style.height=bigheight;
     }
     function normalImg(x) {
        x.style.width=thiswidth;
        x.style.height=thisheight;
     }
  </script> 

  <img id="imageid" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" src="myimage.jpg" alt="image" width="200" >
```

As you can see from the img tag, height is inferred proportional to width by not being specified. Can someone tell me how I can use javascript to derive thisheight from thiswidth?

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you in all ie FF, Chrome, Safari, etc

```
<html>
<body>
  <img id="imageid" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" src="C810623C.gif" alt="image" width="200" > 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var img = document.getElementById('imageid');
        var normsizeimg = img.style.width;
        var bigwidth = 600;

        function bigImg(x)
        { x.style.width = bigwidth; }
        function normalImg(x) { x.style.width = normsizeimg; }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that javascript could preserve the proportionalization of the undeclared dimension the way HTML does.

Answer (score 0):

this is why it's easier to do such things with jquery, some browsers keep dimension values in offsetWidth others don't;

here's a tip of how you can get across this problem

```
var thiswidth=img.offsetWidth;
var thisheight=img.offsetHeight;

//it's non IE browser
if(XMLHttpRequest){
   var thisheight=img.clientHeight;
   var thiswidth=img.clientWidth;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't XMLHttpRequest require an additional connection to the server? I was under the impression that XMLHttpRequest was intended primarily for Ajax-type solutions. Ideally, the javascript should work without making an extra connection, simply by working with the DOM directly in the user's browser.

Comment: you are right, but in this case you are not making any connections, you're just checking if your browser has this function, because IE browsers don't have it. So you are checking if client browser has this function then it's not an IE browser :)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on Firefox (I don't have access to other browsers right now, sorry):

```
<img id="imageid" src="myimage.jpg" alt="image" width="200" >

<script type="text/javascript">
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
img.onload = function(){
    var thiswidth = img.offsetWidth;
    var thisheight = img.offsetHeight;
    var ratio = thisheight/thiswidth;
    var bigwidth = 600;
    var bigheight = bigwidth*ratio;
    img.onmouseover = function bigImg() {
        img.style.width = bigwidth;
        img.style.height = bigheight;
    }
    img.onmouseout = function normalImg(x) {
        img.style.width = thiswidth;
        img.style.height = thisheight;
    }
};
</script>
```

The main differences between this code and yours is that:

1. I'm only accessing the element after it is declared
2. I'm only accessing its properties after the image loads

I'm also only adding the onmouseover and onmouseout attributes later because it makes the HTML look cleaner, but that's optional.

Update: actually, adding the event handlers later *isn't* optional, because they use the calculated `bigwidth` and `bigheight`, which are only available after the image loads.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is precisely "to the point" regarding what was confusing me.

Comment: Just when I think I've got this figured out, something else messes up the mix. I added doctype to the html document, and now the javascript doesn't work. If I remove the doctype, IE fails to center the page using margin: 0 auto. This seems to be true no matter what doctype I use. Suggestions?